# Take selected object on-click, update into DIV

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently working with Angular. My situation is below.

- I have a set of objects, "contacts".
- Inputting custom text into a search box, a table is then "ng-repeated" for each 'contact in main.info'.
- When I click one one of the row entries, this entry is stored to a new object, 'selected'. (with all of that contacts information).

I then want to take that selected entry (which is stored as the 'selected' object) and output that into a different HTML section titled "Contact Information". This section of HTML is stored in a directive Template.

How can I dynamically update the template directive that I have, to include the newly populated 'selected' object?

I cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax to transfer the data in that object into the different section.

Pls, hlp.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an attribute in the directive:

`<my-directive selected-item="{{selectedItem}}"></my-directive>`

And then in the `link` function in the directive just use the `attr.selecteditem`:

```
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
   scope.selectedItem = iAttrs.selecteditem;
}
```

Or if you have an isolate scope:

```
scope: {
   selecteditem: '='
},
link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
   console.log(selecteditem);
}
```